# How do I write a spock test to test the interaction between my class under test and an external utility class?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have the following groovy class

```
import Utils

class HelpController {

   def search = {
       Utils.someFunction()
   }

}
```

Here is my spock groovy spec:

```
import Utils
import grails.test.mixin.*
import HelpController

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(HelpController)
class HelpControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "should call someFunction method in Utils class"() {

        when:
        helpController.search()

        then:
        1 * Utils.someFunction()
    }

}
```

Running the test results in the error:

```
too few invocations for Utils.someFunction() (0 invocations)
```

Utils is a java class. When I step through the spock unit test, it appears that Utils.someFunction() is called so I am a bit confused as to what may be going on. Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement that method, cause you are running a unit test, and the grails application is not running.

Use the annotation `@ConfineMetaClassChanges` for cleaning the metaclass of the class Utils

```
import Utils
import grails.test.mixin.*
import HelpController
import spock.util.mop.ConfineMetaClassChanges

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(HelpController)
@ConfineMetaClassChanges([Utils])
class HelpControllerSpec extends Specification {

    setup(){
        Utils.metaClass.someFunction = {
            //expected response
        }
    }

    void "should call someFunction method in Utils class"() {

        when:
        helpController.search()

        then:
        1 * Utils.someFunction()
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't the Utils.metaClass alteration go inside the scope encompassed by @ConfineMetaClassChanges?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I'm seeing a "No such property: metaclass for Utils" error. I tried extending Expando in Utils but am still getting the same error...note that Utils is a POJO